# Android Studio Sync fails due "failure to parse XML in AndroidManifest.xml"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I decided to update an old app, sadly when I try to sync the project I'm getting the following Gradle Sync error:

> "ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:...\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[17,9]
>   Message: expected start or end tag
>   Affected Modules: app"

After doing my research and forums, the problem seems to be in the AndroidManifest (duh!) when I go to the line 17 I find the Meta-data of my app, and if I add some lines before this, the error moves accordingly to the line.

I have also updated the Gradle to 4.10.1, the Android Plugin version is 3.3.1; and I'm using the "Default Gradle Wrapper"

Here is the Manifest Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myPackage">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/gordotoken"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/gordotoken"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        ///META DATA

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name="myPackage.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="myPackage.dvd" />

        <activity android:name="myPackage.dvai" />

        <activity android:name="myPackage.dvaicat" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                 <intent-filter>
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                     <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{xxx}"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Here is the `build.gradle` for the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        configRelease {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('C:MyKey.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'myApp'
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.14"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.configRelease
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is the build.gradle for the project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'll appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as I seem to be missing some tags in my manifest and at this point I don;t know what I'm doing wrong here :(

Thank you all before hand for your help! :)

Comment: pls add this to gradle file 

    " implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'   "  
--- and pls check styles and fields in xml once and SYNC

Comment: @satyan_android If the author don't use that lib, why would he add this dependency?

Comment: once try it u will get clarity and remove ///META DATA

Answer (score 7):

Remove below line from your `manifest.xml` file

```
///META DATA
```

And replace it with below comments syntax

```
<!—- META DATA —->
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out here already to comment in XML we shouldn't be using `///` but `<!-- >` instead.

Please **replace** `/// META DATA` with `<!-- META DATA->` and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make comment in xml file, you need to use `<!--your comment here-->` this tag. `//` or `/**/` doesn't work

Comment: Hi @Esteban Sustacha, if you've got your answer, please choose one answer as the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, where removing the comments from 
 //**this is a comment** 
to 
 `<!--this is a comment-->` 
worked for me.

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer. Please see Stack Overflow help's How to answer section.

Comment: sure @Pavan, will go through it. Thanks for suggestion